# How do I encounter Thargoids?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Apparently, someone's finally made [First Contact](http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/01/06/years-after-release-someones-found-the-first-aliens-in-elite-dangerous).

Now, I want to try.

Is there a specific place that I need to go to, for my own Thargoid encounter? Do I need to carry anything special with me, either to trigger it or get the most out of it in terms of scanning or other interaction? Has a reliable method been found to trigger the encounter, or is it a random chance based on certain conditions?

Comment: I'm going to say random for now.  Since its been years since the game has been released and people have only now seen a ship of theirs.

Comment: Theres a reddit thread devoted to this, but its certainly not a step by step repeatable process, not sure this question will ever have a straightforward authoritative answer

Comment: The Thargoids were most likely snuck in quietly during an update. expect them to be more fleshed out in future updates/expansions

Comment: I've heard various things involving Unknown Artifacts and certain regions of the Pleiades Nebula. I've also seen one YouTube video where someone did deliberately go out and trigger his own encounter although it did take him several attempts. So, there's obviously certain scenarios where it's more likely than others and I'm sure it's just a matter of time before someone ferrets out a reliable and repeatable process - even if some of it may still be up to random chance. I'm hoping they'll answer here if they do.

Comment: [Here is the Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/comments/5m9t09/thargoids_first_contact_videos_theories/) mentioned earlier, probably your best bet for early tips on locations, loadouts, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to encounter one.

First: this is something that only recently started happening and may stop happening. It appears to be a scripted event and it's likely part of some kind of ongoing plot. (in other words, if you read this months or years later, these encounters may be unavailable or completely different)

Second: it's not necessarily a Thargoid. It certainly does appear alien, but it could be different aliens or even something from humans.

There is definitely randomness involved.

An Unknown Artifact (UA) is not necessary, but it appears it may increase your odds. The majority of commanders that had an encounter had, at least, interacted with a UA in the past. So if you have never even interacted with a UA before, it's probably a good idea to pick one up. Unknown Probes may also help.

So far, all of the events have occurred in the same region of space: **Pleiades, Aries Dark Region** and various things around there.

### The recipe I followed that worked:

1. Go to Maia and visit Professor Palin's lab (requires Horizons) and purchase a *Corrosion Resistant Cargo Rack*. (optional, but avoids damaging ship when carrying UA)
2. Go to one of the known *Unknown Artifact* locations and pick one up (try HIP 17862 6C A coordinates 30.32/-98.6 with SRV). (optional, but seems to increase odds)
3. Plot a route to some random *Pleiades or Aries Dark Region* system. It's unclear if economical route (more jumps) or fastest route (bigger jumps) is more helpful.
4. Go there.
5. Plot a route to the furthest *Pleaides or Aries Dark Region* system you can easily find.
6. Repeatedly go all over that area, back and forth.

(If you don't have Palin access, you can skip the Corrision Resistant Cargo Racks, but if you put a UA in a regular cargo rack your ship will take damage over time.)

https://www.reddit.com/r/EliteDangerous/comments/5m9t09/thargoids_first_contact_videos_theories/ lists some systems encounters were recorded in; you can just pick your destinations from the list (a couple seem to have typos in the name, though).

When it finally happens, the jump *looks* a bit different and then you get a warning about a jump problem. (give you a chance to prepare yourself and fire up the recording software)

From that point, it's very scripted and the only thing you can do is look around your cockpit. At the very end, your ship powers on and you can try to interact with it for a few seconds before it jumps away.

The only extra equipment that seems at all relevant is a **wake scanner**. You can scan the ship with your regular scanners, get a data material and see its outfitting (some normal stuff, 1 pulse laser and some empty slots). When it jumps away, you can scan its wake and get another data material. Discovery scanners don't do anything; warrant scanners don't find anything; cargo scanners don't find anything; and nobody has yet made a dent in its shields with any kind of weapon. Some people have tried to chase it into the wormhole/wake/whatever, but I haven't heard of anybody succeeding at that.

I'd take an **Advanced Discovery Scanner** along, though, since you might as well scan all the systems you're jumping in and get some exploration data.

Comment: BTW, the whole encounter is **awesome**. Make sure to check your sound settings, since the update a few days ago added a new DTS setting specifically for headphones that really improves things.

Comment: How many encounters have you had? I'm looking for a process with relatively reliable repeatability.

Comment: I only had 1 encounter, but I didn't keep trying after that. I believe this matches what people that have had multiple encounters have done, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not definite that you will find them. And while some people think there is requirements to be met. Nobody seems to know that they are.

Apparently alien tech in your cargo bay **may** increase your chances on finding them. They are known as Unknown Artifacts in the game.

One requirement we do know is that you have to be in Hyperspace.